# Ruby - Loading gems form non-default directory

Tags: ruby, rubygems, jruby

I'm trying to load RubyGems from non-default directory, which is by default (please correct me here, if I'm wrong) specified in `Gem.path` array. I've already managed to load the only gem that I've got installed in my non-default directory (which is `'rubyzip'`)  however in only few cases...

I'm using **JRuby 1.7.12** and **Ruby 1.9.3**.

Here are my test results:

**Loading gem from "E:/rb/gems_" directory:**

```
Gem.path
=> ["C:/Users/default/.gem/jruby/1.9", "file:/E:/rb/libraries/jruby.jar!/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/gems/shared"]
Gem.path[0] = "E:/rb/gems_"
=> "E:/rb/gems_"
require 'zip'
=> true
```

In test above, I replaced default user-related gem path with my "E:/rb/gems_" directory, and everything worked just fine.

```
Gem.path.clear
=> []
Gem.path.unshift "E:/rb/gems_"
=> ["E:/rb/gems_"]
require 'zip'
=> true
```

Again, even though I cleared the whole array and replaced it with my own entry, everything worked just fine.

**Loading gem from "E:/rb/gems" directory *(no underscore now. I tested even the possibility with wrong naming)*:**

```
Gem.path.clear
=> []
Gem.path.unshift "E:/rb/gems"
=> ["E:/rb/gems"]
require 'zip'
=> true
```

This test was also completed successfully.

**And here comes the last test:**

```
Gem.path.clear
=> []
require 'zip'
LoadError: no such file to load -- zip
        from org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1065:in `require'
        from file:/E:/rb/libraries/jruby.jar!/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/share
d/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
        from (irb):4:in `evaluate'
        from org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1101:in `eval'
        from org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1501:in `loop'
        from org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1264:in `catch'
        from org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1264:in `catch'
        from file:/E:/rb/libraries/jruby.jar!/META-INF/jruby.home/bin/jirb:13:in
 `(root)'
        from org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1081:in `load'
        from file:/E:/rb/libraries/jruby.jar!/jruby/commands.rb:1:in `(root)'
        from jirb:1:in `(root)'
Gem.path
=> []
Gem.path.clear.unshift "E:/rb/gems"
=> ["E:/rb/gems"]
require 'zip'
LoadError: no such file to load -- zip
        from org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1065:in `require'
        from file:/E:/rb/libraries/jruby.jar!/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/share
d/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
        from (irb):7:in `evaluate'
        from org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1101:in `eval'
        from org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1501:in `loop'
        from org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1264:in `catch'
        from org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1264:in `catch'
        from file:/E:/rb/libraries/jruby.jar!/META-INF/jruby.home/bin/jirb:13:in
 `(root)'
        from org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1081:in `load'
        from file:/E:/rb/libraries/jruby.jar!/jruby/commands.rb:1:in `(root)'
        from jirb:1:in `(root)'
Gem.path
=> ["E:/rb/gems"]
```

And here comes the "interesting" part. I tried to load the `'zip'` file when there was no entry in the `Gem.path` array, which obviously failed, that is of course more than fine result. However, when I filled the array with exactly one entry pointing to the non-default directory with my RubyZip gem, it failed again!

My question is: Why does the second atemp of loading the RubyGem failed? Is there something I'm overlooking? Is this approach of loading gems from non-default directory right, or is there a better one?

Comment: You can always require an absolute path. I would only modify the search path if you have a lot of files you are requiring from a nonstandard location.

Comment: Have you looked at RVM Gemsets (http://rvm.io/gemsets/basics) those allows you to have specific, separated gemsets that you can define. I can elaborate in an answer if needed.

Comment: Thanks for your comments! Solution Max has suggested is pretty much correct but doesn't fit my goal. I'm attemping to completely change the default directory for Ruby Gems with preserving all of the functionalities. The other comment written by Martin is once again correct. But I don't want to rely on RVM. In fact, it would be impossible to achieve what I want by relying on RVM. However, let me thank both of you guys for your comments! I really appreciate your work! :)

Comment: You could just add to `Gem.default_path() << YOUR_FULL_PATH`

Comment: Hi looseseal_90, thank you for your comment! Unfortunately, that didn't work at all, see the result for yourself:

`E:\rb\libraries>java -jar jruby.jar -S irb
Gem::path.clear.unshift "E:/rb/gems"
=> ["E:/rb/gems"]
Gem::Specification.find_all_by_name "rubyzip"
=> [#<Gem::Specification:0x7fa rubyzip-1.1.4>]
exit

E:\rb\libraries>java -jar jruby.jar -S irb
Gem::default_path.clear.unshift "E:/rb/gems"
=> ["E:/rb/gems"]
Gem::Specification.find_all_by_name "rubyzip"
=> []`